# Why is my step length messed up? (turning tracks into steps)

Tags: r

Does anyone know, why my step length sl_ is not shown in meters?

I'm using the amt package and try to perform an integrated step selection analysis based on gps movement data.

I'm quite new to this and didn't find much with searching in google. My guess is, that it's messed up because of the CRS, do I have to use UTM coordinates?

Unfortunately I can't post my data set, if you need more information I guess I could create some random movement data.

Thanks for taking the time to help out.

After importing my data, I converted it to tracks.

```
trk <- make_track(data, E, N, datetime, crs = 4326)

> class(trk)
[1] "track_xyt"  "track_xy"   "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Then I performed the `steps()` function.

```
stp <- steps(trk)
```

It worked well, just my sl_ is shown like this:

```
7.914206e-04
5.160599e-04
...
```

```
library(amt)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

setwd("path")

data <- read.csv2("test.csv", skip = 1, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
glimpse(data)

# format chr to dttm
data$datetime <- strptime(data$datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# set timezone
tz(data$datetime) <- "Europe/Berlin"

# make track out of data frame
trk.test <- make_track(data, E, N, datetime, crs = 4326)
class(trk.test)

# default plotting methods
plot(trk.test)

# turning tracks into steps
stp.test <- steps(trk.test)
view(stp.test)
```

```
WGS 84, EPSG 4326


structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    E = c(7.3900622244, 7.3919191098, 7.3993466517, 7.4051295235, 
    7.4166952672, 7.4190826913, 7.418817422, 7.4220537081, 7.4201437687, 
    7.4050234158), N = c(50.3376469514, 50.3356839582, 50.3288400089, 
    50.323905999, 50.3209349823, 50.322261329, 50.3302724634, 
    50.3436420387, 50.3467191632, 50.3597173613), datetime = c("2022-11-11 07:00:05", 
    "2022-11-11 08:00:12", "2022-11-11 11:02:05", "2022-11-11 12:00:35", 
    "2022-11-11 13:01:07", "2022-11-11 14:00:24", "2022-11-11 16:00:04", 
    "2022-11-11 17:00:12", "2022-11-11 22:01:01", "2022-11-11 23:00:44"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, how do you know it is not shown in meters? Just because it is very small?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @January . I checked distance between points in QGIS. For example, the distance should be 266 m, what I get as sl_ is 5.988699e-03. I'll update my question with a test data set and the code. There, values look better, but they are not matching the measurements in QGIS either.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (instead of a table like you have). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thanks @ Shawn Hemelstrand. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It was actually just adding the argument `lonlat = TRUE`. The default of `steps()`-function is `lonlat = FALSE`.